# Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState', not running properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I've just starting learning flutter and I have been following a tutorial. I copied the guy word for word and somehow an error message is generated. This is the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/login_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I have a directory called pages containing a login_page.dart. file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

There is a red line underneath Login page on line 3 of the login_page.dart file with the following error message:

Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'. (Documentation)  Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.

I expect this to run and create a basic UI but it fails to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Flutter has two type of widget.

1. Stateless
2. Statefull

First widget dosen't have any kind of state.And Statefull widget have state.
In your code you have created state-full widget without state.
Your code should be look like this.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
const LoginPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}
```